# Zonal statistics in R as in GIS (for a point, not polygon)

Tags: r, statistics, extract

I have multiple rasters in a folder. I need to extract mean of each of these rasters over a pixel (I do points and note polygons).

It says extract can be used for points, lines and polygons too.
BUT for the function (fun = mean). I would like to know by this method, if I must obligatorily do fun='mean' ? Because I have points in my shapefile and not polygon... ?
The points are on each pixel of my raster

Can you help me please ?Thank you

It's here the code I want to do :

```
test <- list.files("my_path", pattern = "\\.tif$", full=TRUE)
STACK <- stack(ff)

SHAPE <- shapefile("my_path/supplimentY.shp")

extr <- extract(STACK, SHAPE, *fun='mean'*, na.rm=TRUE, df=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the `extract` example:

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(ncol=36, nrow=18, vals=1:(18*36))

###############################
# extract values with points
###############################
xy <- cbind(-50, seq(-80, 80, by=20))
sp <- SpatialPoints(xy)
raster::extract(r, sp)
```

and from the documentation:

> If y represents points, fun is only used when a buffer is used

so you should not supply a function to the `fun` argument since there are no values to summarize, because points fall in one single pixel of each layer in the stack.

If you want a summary of the values near points, you can specify the radius of a buffer around each point from which to extract cell values with the `buffer` argument. Or you can change the `method` argument to 'bilinear', in this way the returned values are interpolated from the values of the four nearest raster cells.

Comment: OOOH thank you so much. 
Yes I was telling myself that we should not put the fun function. I doubted that.
Thank you very much for the clarification and all informations provided @Elia

Comment: Hello. I come back to you again.

I adopted the procedure. I specify that my shapefile contains two entities of layers. (which are points)

When I do:

**`raster::extract(r, sp)`**

I get an error message, do you know where the problem is please? 

The error is here :

Error in res[i] <- readBin(x@file@con, what = dtype, n = 1, size = dsize, : replacement has length zero

Comment: Can you share your data? I don't know why you get this error and without the data it is hard to guess what happened.